# Vue js image selectable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm looking to make the img tag selectable. I mean to obtain a boolean value true/false if the photo it's selected or deselected. Any ideas?

```
<h2 class="headline mb-2 text-xs-center">Choose your hero:</h2>
<v-layout row wrap primary-title v-for="hero in heroes" :key="hero.id">
  <v-flex xs6>
    <v-avatar size="80px" class="grey lighten-1">
      <img v-bind:src="`${hero.href}`" alt="avatar">
    </v-avatar>
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex xs6 class="text-xs-right">
    <v-subheader>{{hero.name}}€</v-subheader>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
</v-card>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

      data: () => ({

          bases: [{
              id: 1,
              name: "Spiderman",
              href: "../../static/spiderman.jpg"
          }, {
              id: 2,
              name: "Batman",
              href: "../../static/batman.jpg"
          }]
      })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want the images to act like a radio group, where only one can be selected at any time?

Comment: Hello Roy, yes that's it's. It just should be posible to select one, not both at the same time. Yes, exactly like a radio button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple example that you can make it selectable

```
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                //...
            }
        },
        methods: {
            selectHero(hero){
                this.$set(hero, 'selected', (hero.selected ? false:true)) //!hero.selected
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

in template

```
<img :src="hero.href" alt="avatar" :class="{selected: hero.selected}" @click="selectHero(hero)">
```

and if you want to select only one item

```
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                //...
                selectedHero: {}
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getSelectedHero(){
                return this.selectedHero;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<img :src="hero.href" alt="avatar" :class="{selected: selectedHero.id == hero.id}" @click="selectedHero = hero">

<style>
    img.selected{
        border: solid 2px green;
        /* and other styles ... */
    }
</style>
```

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer Damon, should be like you said, just select one item, not both at the same time, so like a radio button behavior. I just understand your code, but I cannot be able to see any image selected, the code looks executed without any error  but I can't detect how the image is selected...

Comment: Yes, that's it! :)